# Getting the author of MessageReference object

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, attributeerror

My Discord bot has a command that needs to check 2 discord user ID's: `ctx.message.author.id` and the author ID of the "reply" message.

Getting the `id` of the first user is easy, because this is just the `id` of the one who used the command:

```
def check_two_ids(ctx):

    id1 = ctx.message.author.id
    # come other code
```

Getting the second `id` is way more difficult as the command only  works if it is used as a reply. So I tried to use the `MessageReference` object and get the second `id` out of that somehow. Here is what I tried:

```
def check_two_ids(ctx):

    id1 = ctx.message.author.id
    message_reference = ctx.message.reference
    id2 = message.reference.author.id
    # do some more stuff with these two ids
```

Running this code returns an error: `AttributeError: 'MessageReference' object has no attribute 'author'`. I thought this would be similar to a normal `Message` object which has these parameters.

Can I get the second ID with this approach somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `MessageReference` doesn't directly have an author attribute is because it simply [isn't provided by Discord API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#message-reference-object-message-reference-structure). However under certain circumstances (when the reference is pointing to a reply), Discord API will provide the resolved message object for the reference which you can access with [`message.reference.resolved`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.MessageReference.resolved).

```
def check_two_ids(ctx):
    id1 = ctx.message.author.id
    message_reference = ctx.message.reference
    if not (message_reference and message_reference.resolved and
            isinstance(message_reference.resolved, discord.Message)):
        return
    id2 = message_reference.resolved.author.id
```

There's a few caveats with the `resolved` attribute though:

- It could be `None`, Discord API fails to fetch it.
- It count be `DeletedReferencedMessage`, the reference was deleted.